# How to verify the body context using Assert command

Tags: java, testng, rest, assert, verify

I want to pass my test.When I run my test it gets fail because expected and actual is not matching. How to do with assert command?

When I copy the actual value it shows like an error:

> {"level":"error","msg":"REG_DEV_EXISTS_00","meta":[]}"}

Here is my code:

```
public class registerCounter {
    @Test(dataProvider = "register")
    public void md5JsonTest(String secret,String mac,String id, String md5Hash) {

        given().
                parameters("s", secret).parameters("m",mac).parameters("d",id).
                when().
                get("http://baseUrl/register/device").
                then().
                assertThat().
                body("md5", equalTo(md5Hash));
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "register")
    public Object[][] createMD5TestData() {

        return new String[][] {

                {"b30b33","d3r34ret34t5r","8","REG_DEV_EXISTS_00"}

        };
    }

}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: XML path md5 doesn't match.  
Expected:  REG_DEV_EXISTS_00    
Actual: {"level":"error","msg":"REG_DEV_EXISTS_00","meta":[]}
```

I put containsString

```
java.lang.AssertionError: XML path md5 doesn't match. 
Expected: a string containing "REG_DEV_EXISTS_00" 
Actual: {"level":"error","msg":"REG_DEV_EXISTS_00","meta":[]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assert :

- Reminder : If Assert get failed the execution or program get terminated there itself.
- It can be used as follows:

  ```
  Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.id("your_element_id")).getText(), "Expected Text");

                           OR

  Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.id("your_element_id")).getText(), "Expected Text","Assert failed - text does not match");
  ```

Comment: hai i am using rest-assured. can you check my code and say correct assert command?

Answer (score 0):

You could do an Assert that the actual value [containsString](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/usage) of the expected value.

```
assertThat().
body("md5", containsString(md5Hash));
```

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError: XML path md5 doesn't match.
Expected: a string containing "REG_DEV_EXISTS_00"
  Actual: {"level":"error","msg":"REG_DEV_EXISTS_00","meta":[]}
I got this error what to do to pass my test ?

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing your expected value `(REG_DEV_EXISTS_00)` with a piece of JSON that contains the expected value and some other data

```
({"level":"error","msg":"REG_DEV_EXISTS_00","meta":[]})
```

Either use the containsString assert as kirbycope suggested, or parse the JSON and extract the relevant `msg` field before doing the comparison.

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError: XML path md5 doesn't match.
Expected: a string containing "REG_DEV_EXISTS_00"
  Actual: {"level":"error","msg":"REG_DEV_EXISTS_00","meta":[]}